# Laravel Сессия пропадает после редиректа на поддомен

Tags: php, laravel

Доброго времени суток, друзья. Помогите разобраться, не получается передавать сессию между поддоменами приложения в Laravel?

При авторизации пользователя, его авторизирует метод attempt фремворка Laravel и редиректит на поддомен(там лежит профиль пользователя), но на поддомене на который мы редиректим пользователя не передается сессия этого пользователя, и по этому на самом поддомене он как будто не зарегистрирован, хотя на основном домене с которого мы делаем редирект сессия есть и все нормально работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В браузере посмотрите в инструментах разработчика, вкладка Сеть, что вам сервер присылает (какую куку).

Comment: Оно обновляет url с поддоменом и возвращает на страницу login так как на поддомене нету сессии.

Comment: Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlJuVzZDQnBBV1wvOUxQTkVOOGNhaVV3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlpYZndNRG5WUWpVQzhpdkxXMER6cGp5bUdaMElqa3lFZGlCNjZtQkhYQU13cDJidzN4OGhlYVdrNU5lWkJkZElPMEx3XC9iMEFEanV2enZBaGtJMFV0UT09IiwibWFjIjoiNGFhOTZmODA2NzI0Y2IxYjc0MWE3ZjRiZmMyNzllOTRmZWZkYTI4ZDRlZDc4ODRkODA5YWM5NDNjMzRkMWYzYSJ9; expires=Tue, 27-Jun-2017 18:30:18 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly

Comment: `path=/;` тут должен домен указываться, чтобы кука была видна в поддоменах тоже.

Comment: Ок, а не подскажете какой функцией запихнуть можно туда домен? А то я только пару месяцев с Laravel работаю.

Comment: Про `path` попутал, его не надо трогать, нужно `domain` задать в config\session.php. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26469765/5441700

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/a/26469765/5441700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26469765/5441700)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев к вопросу было выяснено, что сессионные куки авторизации устанавливаются без явного указания домена. В результате они действуют только на основном домене (где и были установлены).

Чтобы сессионные куки авторизации были видны на поддоменах, нужно в файле **config/session.php** явно указать свой домен

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

так

```
'domain' => 'your.site',
```

(раньше нужна была стартовая точка в имени домена, чтобы куки были видны на поддоменах, теперь по новым правилам этого не требуется).